# Issue with accessing previous data being stored in React component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, axios, infinite-scroll

I'm in ReactJS trying to implement infinite scrolling using Axios and the useReducer hook. I'm receiving data from the GIPHY API just fine but the problem is that when I get the the bottom of the viewport, new gifs are simply replacing the ones that are originally being loaded onto the webpage instead of creating new containers for them.

I know for a fact that there is no issue with my mapping method or the way that I've set up the intersection observer to trigger the get request for the next gifs. I'm using useReducer to store the previous state and add the additional gifs to the original ones.

I keep getting the error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'gifs.data.map')"
In light of this, I thought that I was mutating the response from the API by putting it inside an additional array to store the previous data but no cigar.

Here is the code from the reducer:

```
else if(action.type === 'success') {
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    data: prevData => {
      return [...prevData, action.res.data]
  }
}
```

Here is my mapping method:

```
<div className='infinite-scroll-gifs'>
  {gifs.data.map((gif, index) => {
    if(gifs.data.length === index + 1) {
      return (
        <div ref={infiniteScrollTriggerRef} key={gif.id}>
          <img src={gif.images.fixed_height.url} alt='Random GIF'></img>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }}
```

The shape of the object that the GIPHY API returns is as follows:

```
{
  "data":
    [
      {
        gifData
      },
      {
        gifData
      },
      {
        gifData
      }
    ]
}
```

This is my first question on Stack Overflow and I've been trying to work this out for four days now, haha. If anybody has any idea what I can do to possibly work please let me know! Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: When are you  receiving that? Are you sure that `data` or even `gifs` are defined?

Comment: Yes, I can display the data if I don't try storing the previous posts with the new posts using data: prevData => { return [...prevData, action.res.data] } it's only when I use a function state to store the previous data alongside the new data that I receive the error. I originally thought it was because I was mutating the shape of the object being returned from the API by adding an additional array but I changed my code to account for that and nothing.

Comment: Can you share a bit more of the code? We can't even see where `gifs` come from. Or even better, create a https://codesandbox.io/index2 with a running example.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. If you follow this link you can see the code in its entirety.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63957743/issue-accessing-data-from-api-return-when-implementing-infinite-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is how you are providing the initial data to `useReducer`.

```js
const MyComponent = () => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(gifReducer, initialState);

}
```

Here in the initialState variable, you need to give default values to your state.

```js
const initialState = {
    gifs: [],
    loading: false
}
```

So that when you render the gifs, it will not through an undefined error.

Also in your `gifReducer` function, you may give default values as well.

I think this should fix the error. Or else, please paste the complete code for your `JSX` and `reducer` functions.

Comment: Hello, first of all thanks for answering! I just tried using an initial state variable inside of my reducer but it didn't change anything. In my RandomGIF component I'm using the data returned from the reducer as const { loading, error, data: gifs } = useInfiniteScroll(url).

I can't put all of the code into the comment because of the character limit but I've made a new post with the full JSX if you have the time to look at it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63957743/issue-accessing-data-from-api-return-when-implementing-infinite-scrolling